# GAN's generator gradients are None

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, gradient, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on a GAN that gets a random seeds with shape (batch_size, 10) and returns a tensor with shape (batch_size, 50).
When I try to train the generator, it's gradients are always None.
I tried to freeze the discriminator parameters and train a model that contains the generator and the discriminator, and I also tried writing a custom train function for the generator, but it all failed.

Here is my code for training the generator:

```
@tf.function
def TrainGenerator(generator, discriminator, optimizer):
    X_gan = tf.random.uniform((32, 10))
    y_gan = tf.ones((32, 1))

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = discriminator(generator(X_gan, training=True), training=False)
        main_loss = tf.reduce_mean(keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_gan, y_pred))
        loss = tf.add_n([main_loss] + generator.losses)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, generator.trainable_variables))

    return loss
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
```

Thanks for your kind help.